# Function that returns even numbers from a list and halves them

Tags: python, loops, concatenation

So I am having trouble concatenating this, I am not allowed to use .append(), and right now Im getting the error 'int' object not iterable.

````
def halveEvens(l):
    num = []
    for n in l:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            num += (n // 2)
        return num



print(halveEvens([10,21,32,42,55]))```
````

Comment: If you cannot use `append` then try with `num += [n // 2]` where square brackets make a 1-element list and `num` can be extended with it (but it cannot be extended directly with integers as the error implies). Also dedent the `return` statement so that function returns *after* for loop completes not in the very first turn.

Comment: or you can go for list comprehensions: `num = [n // 2 for n in the_list if n % 2 == 0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum(x//2 for x in numbers if x%2 == 0)`

is probably how I would do it

if you just want to collect them (without summing them)

generator `(x//2 for x in numbers if x%2 == 0)`  would be evaluated as you iterate it

or list comprehension that is evaluated immediatly
`[x//2 for x in numbers if x%2 == 0]`

Comment: I think the OP is after a list (comprehension), not the sum.